# C++ implement class constructs instance of another classes depending on string it consumes

Tags: c++, c++98

I need to implement one abstract class, three its concrete subclasses, class which goal to create one of this three classes instances and last class executor of three classes. Requirements are c++98, and not to use if/elseif/else to construct class instance, like i did in a Maker class method make Form. What mechanism i need to avoid if / elseif / else?

For example:

**test.h**

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
#include <iostream>

class Executor {
private:
    const std::string name;
public:
    Executor(const std::string &name = "") {};

    const std::string getname() const {return name;}
};

class BForm {
private:
    const std::string _name;
public:
    BForm(const std::string &name = "") : _name(name) {};
    virtual ~BForm() {};

    virtual void execute(const Executor &src) = 0;

    const std::string getname() {return _name;}
    virtual const std::string gettarget() = 0;
};

class Form1 : public BForm{
private:
    std::string _target;
public:
    Form1(const std::string &target = "") : BForm("form1"), _target(target) {};
    virtual ~Form1() {};

    virtual void execute(const Executor &src) {
        std::cout << src.getname() << " exec form1 target:" << _target << std::endl;
    }

    virtual const std::string gettarget() {return _target;}
};

class Form2 : public BForm {
private:
    std::string _target;
public:
    Form2(const std::string &target = "") : BForm("form2"), _target(target) {};
    virtual ~Form2() {};

    virtual void execute(const Executor &src) {
        std::cout << src.getname() << " exec form2 target:" << _target << std::endl;
    };
    virtual const std::string gettarget() {return _target;}
};

class Form3 : public BForm {
private:
    std::string _target;
public:
    Form3(const std::string &target = "") : BForm("form3"), _target(target) {};
    virtual ~Form3() {};

    virtual void execute(const Executor &src) {
        std::cout << src.getname() << " exec form3 target:" << _target << std::endl;
    };
    virtual const std::string gettarget() {return _target;}
};

class Maker {
public:
    BForm *makeForm(const std::string &name, const std::string &target)
    {
        /* need to avoid */
        if (name == "form1")
            return new Form1(target);
        else if (name == "form2")
            return new Form2(target);
        else
            return new Form3(target);
    }
};

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"

int main() {
    Maker maker;
    BForm *form;
    Executor exec("executor");

    form = maker.makeForm("form1", "A");
    std::cout << form->getname() << " " << form->gettarget() << std::endl;
    form->execute(exec);
    delete form;
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Well, you could you a `switch` statement, but that is not too different from `if` and `else`. Not sure what you are trying to do here, really. Can you explain a bit more what exactly the requirements are?

Comment: Side note: do not put a semicolon after an empty function definition. I mean, write for example `virtual ~Form3() {}` instead of `virtual ~Form3() {};`. The extra semicolon does no harm in this case, but is interpreted as an empty statement.

Comment: Can you explain what is so terrible about using a few `if` statements?  This seems a strange requirement.

Comment: @PaulSanders I suppose the teacher wants to guide the students away from a code-centric towards a data-centric coding style which is often a good idea (better maintainability, less code). Of course it's not terrible here but imagine you write a PCL6 compiler and you want to transform the string tokens into internal representations ... and maybe later you want to output strings again from these representations. How long is your if/else sequence? How often do you have to write it?

Comment: If this is an assignment, the teacher should have given you some hints, examples or references to literature. But a teacher still teaching C++98 is a bad teacher anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could typedef a pointer to function and then use a map from string to this type (pointer to function). And then use your parameter with indexer syntax to access the correct pointer to function.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

// The class definitions with a virtual function hello() common to all
class Base { public: virtual void hello() = 0; };
class Derived1 : public Base { public: void hello() { std::cout << "Derived1"; } };
class Derived2 : public Base { public: void hello() { std::cout << "Derived2"; } };

// The object making functions
Base* Maker1() { return new Derived1; }
Base* Maker2() { return new Derived2; }

int main()
{
    // In C++98, without auto, it's worthwhile to typedef complicated types.
    // The first one is a function type returning a pointer to Base...
    typedef Base* MakerT();
    // ... the second one is a map type projecting strings to such function pointers
    typedef std::map<std::string, MakerT*> StrToMakerT;

    /// The actual map projecting strings to maker function pointers
    StrToMakerT strToMaker;
    // Fill the map
    strToMaker["D1"] = &Maker1;
    strToMaker["D2"] = &Maker2;

    // user input
    std::string choice;

    // as long as output works, input works, and the user didn't say "Q":
    while (std::cout << "Please input 'D1' or 'D2' or 'Q' for quit: " 
        && std::cin >> choice 
        && choice != "Q")
    {
        // Prevent adding new entries to the map foir unknown strings
        if (strToMaker.find(choice) != strToMaker.end())
        {
            // Simply look the function up again, the iterator type is too 
            // cumbersome to write in C++98
            Base* b = (*strToMaker[choice])();
            b->hello();
            std::cout << '\n';
            delete b;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Didn't find your choice, try again.\n";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Thank you, good bye\n";
}
```

Comment: I added an example program.

Comment: By the way this approach is useful in many situations, like if you are implementing API handlers and, in general, have long switch statements.

Comment: Thank you too much! it's forbidden to use containers in this ex. and i am not familiar with them, i implement your advice as:

Comment: No ifs and no containers? Impossible. Maybe it's en educational exercise the the teacher wants you use the ternary operator? `variable = (condition) ? expressionTrue : expressionFalse;` Which is a shorthand for if / else.

Comment: Code added to class Maker both array of pointers to functions which calls for constructor and array of strings for them

Comment: Essentially a map, but manually implemented, ok.